# Heroku returning H13 error from Node(Express) with SSL

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku

When trying to access the site via **https://example.org (works)** BUT **https://www.example.org (doesn't work)**

- The issue seems to be weird and confusing. I see the sub-domain redirected to my root domain.

  curl -I https://www.example.org

  HTTP/1.1 302 Found

  Server: Cowboy

  Connection: keep-alive

  X-Powered-By: Express

  Location: https://example.org

When the sub-domain is trying to connect to your application somewhere in the middle the connection is getting closed without reaching your app or getting a response from your app.

- Might be this related to how routings are configured in Express?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access this through a browser or through different client? (CLI, package, ...). It might be possible that you need to allow "follow redirects". Plain curl uses: ` -L, --location      Follow redirects` as an option.

Comment: Does your public DNS contain a 'www' record? If you `ping example.org` it should work - if you `ping www.example.org` does it also resolve? As Christoph said you may be able to fix this by allowing redirects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to solve with the redirects, trying to access through the browser. It's weird because the DNS contains the www record but the ping doesn't resolve :/